# GitVersion in Azure DevOps throwing Exception for feature branches

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, gitversion

We have been migrating our existing pipelines for our projects to use GitVersion and yml files instead of Azure DevOps UI steps.  We did the initial run and testing 2 months ago and it's been working fine for some projects already.

Today, I'm trying to migrate another one to use GitVersion and getting errors like following for same set up and GitVersion.yml.

When I try to build the **feature** branches, I got the following error at gitversion/execute@0 step:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Gitversion could not determine which
> branch to treat as the development branch (default is 'develop') nor
> release-able branch (default is 'main' or 'master'), either locally or
> remotely. Ensure the local clone and checkout match the requirements
> or considering using 'GitVersion Dynamic Repositories'

It works for builds on develop and master branches

- develop branch - OK
- master branch - OK
- feature/xxx or features/xxx - Not OK

**GitVersion.yml**

```
next-version: 15.0.0 
assembly-informational-format: '{SemVer}'
ignore:
  commits-before: '2021-01-01T00:00:00'
branches:
  develop:
    tag: beta
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: alpha
  release:
    tag: rc
    increment: Minor
    track-merge-target: true
  main:
    track-merge-target: true
  hotfix:
    tag: rc
```

**Pipeline Yml**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
    - releases/*
    - release/*
    - hotfixes/*
    - hotfix/*
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - src/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'release'

steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 100000
  clean: true
  persistCredentials: true
  
- task: gitversion/setup@0
  displayName: gitversion/setup
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.x

- task: gitversion/execute@0
  displayName: gitversion/execute
  inputs:
    useConfigFile: true
    configFilePath: GitVersion.yml

- script: echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(GitVersion.SemVer)"
```

Other build steps are removed for clarity.

I tried to add regex: `^features?[/-]` (which is the default regex) under feature: in GetVersion.yml.  But error still the same.

I did have both *develop* and *master* branches in my repo.

[image]

Could you please suggest me how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a different yml for feature branches.  It looks like that one doesn't have it in the includes?  I'd expect with fetchDepth it would have worked.  In the latest Sprint roll-out, they changed the default value of new pipelines to have the shallow fetch to 1.  You can see it by going to the yaml tab of the triggers view.  I think it is collateral from the [tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-209-update?tabs=yaml#do-not-sync-tags-when-fetching-a-git-repository) work they were doing.

Comment: I created the test feature branch from -develop branch.  So, I can confirm that they have the same yml content.  I had to put fetchDepth to 100K because it's an old Repo (5 years old) and has many commits and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our DevOps expert managed to solve the issue by changing the following lines.

He mentioned that it might be related to recent Microsoft release as per @Matt comment.

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 1  <<< updated this line
  clean: true
  persistCredentials: true
  
- task: gitversion/setup@0
  displayName: gitversion/setup
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.x

- script: git fetch --unshallow --all  <<< added this line
```